# Viewing outstanding requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

Is there any way to view what requests Protractor are waiting on? I'm trying to debug flaky state testing, but it is hard to tell whether a button didn't trigger a response or if Protractor didn't bother to wait.

TL;DR: How can I view the remaining promises on the Protractor control flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is to start protractor in a *debug mode* and put [`browser.debugger()`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#pausing-to-debug) breakpoint before the problem block of code.

See more information at [Debugging Protractor Tests](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md#debugging-protractor-tests).

---

On the other hand, you can catch the [*chromedriver service logs*](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging) that look like:

```
[2.389][INFO]: COMMAND FindElement {
   "sessionId": "b6707ee92a3261e1dc33a53514490663",
   "using": "css selector",
   "value": "input"
}
[2.389][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[2.389][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations
[2.398][INFO]: Waiting for pending navigations...
[2.398][INFO]: Done waiting for pending navigations
[2.398][INFO]: RESPONSE FindElement {
   "ELEMENT": "0.3367185448296368-1"
}
```

Might also give you a clue of what is happening.

For this, you need to start chrome with `--verbose` and `--log-path` arguments:

```
{
     browserName: "chrome",
     specs: [
         "*.spec.js"
     ],
     chromeOptions: {
         args: [
             "--verbose",
             "--log-path=/path/to/the/log/file"
         ]
     }
 }
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

For firefox, you can turn on and view logs by setting [`webdriver.log.driver` and `webdriver.log.file` firefox profile settings](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#settings).

See also:

- [Monitoring JSON wire protocol logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812554/monitoring-json-wire-protocol-logs)
- [How to change firefox profile](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/tree/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile)